# CRTP and virtual function overhead method call

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, crtp

How do I prevent function call overhead  using CRTP? The details of the classes are ommited but I basically have a base class A and some other classes that inherit from A but implement a specialized function that is called from A. The classes that inherit from A, have a specialized function that get repeated many times (see below). The CRTP implementation is in my benchmarks equally fast as the CRTP implementation but slower than the flat class implementation, i.e. no inheritance. How can that be? Initially I tackled the problem with virtual functions as follows:

```
// VIRTUAL EXAMPLE
class VIRTUAL_A{
  public:
  virtual void do_inner() {};

  void do_stuff(size_t N){
        for (size_t i = 0; i<N ; i++){
            this->do_inner();
        }
  }
};

class VIRTUAL_B : public VIRTUAL_A{
  public:
  void do_inner() override{
    //do heavy computation
  }
};
```

which I then translated into CRTP as:

```
// CRTP EXAMPLE
template <template T>
class CRTP_A{
  public:
    void do_stuff(size_t N){
        for (size_t i = 0; i<N ; i++){
            static_cast<T&>(*this).do_inner();
        }
    }

 };

class CRTP_B : public CRTP_A<CRTP_B>{
  void do_inner(){
    // heavy computation
  }
};
```

However when I compare it to a flat class, the flat class runs faster

```
// FLAT EXAMPLE
class FLAT_A{
  public:
  void do_inner(){
  //heavy computation
}

void do_stuff(size_t N){
  for (size_t i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ){
    this->do_inner();
    }
  }

};
```

(Class details are omitted) real benchmark scores:

[image]

Numbers are in seconds for an arbitrary test case. The difference is consistent as a function of N.

Now my questions are:

- Is there overhead in the CRTP for function call at runtime?
- Am I missing something in the class initializing such that the compiler cannot inline the derived class in the CRTP approach?

Edit::
Assemby output

## CRTP CLASS

[image]

## Flat class

[image]

## Virtual class

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the precise benchmark and the compiled assembly. Are you certain the compiler is not optimizing e.g. the loop away?

Comment: It is a bit complicated as the entire code base was written in cython and I am currently exploring translating it to cpp. I am no expert in cpp but the disassembly code can be found here (https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/QY5OyItY/0). The relevant "heavy load" function that is using CRPT is at address (0x25750).

Comment: @Quimby added the relevant sectors from the assembly in the post. All three outputs are different with the virtual call being the largest. There are 4 additional lines in the CRTP function compared to the flat class. I have no clue on how to interpret it further, do you have any ideas?